# Is function not called inside typeid?

Tags: c++

Is a function not called inside a typeid? Consider the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int mul10(int &s)
{
    static int count = 1;
    cout << "Evaluating call " << count << endl;
    count++;
    s *= 10;
    return(s);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    cout << typeid(mul10(i)).name() << endl;
    cout << i << endl;
    return(0);
}
```

So here the output is

```
int
5
```

So clearly the value of `i` did not change and also the function `mul10` was not actually called. Is that how typeid arguments evaluated?

Comment: It's not necessary to call the function, the type of the result is already known by the compiler.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: It's more than "not necessary"; the compiler *must not* call the function in this case.  E.g. this program is correct: `int x() { return 1 / 0; } int main() { typeid(x()); }`

Comment: @M.M I see that you left a reference on an answer to back up your statement, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The operand of `typeid` is only evaluated if it is a glvalue of polymorphic class type. Since the return type of `mul10`, namely `int`, is not a polymorphic class type, the operand is not evaluated, meaning that `mul10` is not called.

Comment: reference: C++14 [expr.typeid]/3

Comment: Thanks Brian. That explains a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If we go to the draft C++ standard it tell us that unless the expression glvalue of a polymorphic class type the result is based on the static type of the object. From section `5.2.8` *[expr.typeid]* with emphasis mine:

> When typeid is applied to an **expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type, the result refers
>   to a std::type_info object representing the static type of the expression.** Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-topointer
>   (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) conversions are not applied to the expression. If the type of the
>   expression is a class type, the class shall be completely-defined. The expression is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5).